# Iterating through nested objects/arrays

Tags: javascript, loops, yui3

I'm trying to iterate through an object that can have several levels of arrays.

Eg.

I start with:

```
var htmlString = {
    "div": [{
        "attributes": {
            "class": "myDivClass"
        },
        "p": [{
            "attributes": {
                "class": "myPClass"
            }
        }]
    }]
};
```

Now let's add something else:

```
var htmlString = {
    "div": [{
        "attributes": {
            "class": "myDivClass"
        },
        "p": [{
            "attributes": {
                "class": "myPClass"
            },
            "span": [{
                "attributes": {
                    "class": "mySpanClass"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

The code I'm working on will have the same sort of shape as:

```
var childNode = document.createElement("myChildElement");
for (key in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (key == "attributes") {
            childNode.setAttributes(myAttributes); // loop through attributes on the element
        }
        else {
            //the same code ad infinitum
            var childChildNode = document.createElement("myChildChildElement");
            // etc etc....
        }
    }
}
parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
```

The rules of each extra element are the same, so I should be able to just loop down this data structure the same way for both pieces of code, I'm just not sure how, although I'll bet there is a while() loop in there somewhere. Can anyone tell me?

P.S. Native javascript, please, no jQuery! (Although, if you have YUI3 answer I'd be very interested).

Comment: There is no JSON in your examples, only JavaScript objects. To me it seems like you have to create a recursive function.

Comment: This is not the actual code I'm working on, but JSONLint was happy with this as valid JSON. And yes, the recursive function for this is exactly what I'm asking for, thanks.

Comment: JSON, the *data exchange format*, is a subset of JavaScript's object literal syntax, so yes, certain object literals are also valid JSON, but that does not make your problem have anything to do with JSON. You are asking how to recursively process nested JavaScript objects.... not at all related to JSON. I will correct your question...

Comment: @user1565354 In the context of a JavaScript program, JSON is a String value. If what you have is not a string, it's not JSON. The notations in your code are *object literals*. The object literal notation looks very similar to JSON, except that object literals appear in JavaScript source code (as expressions, which are evaluated as Object values), whereas JSON is usually kept in separate .json files. If you really wanted to define JSON in JavaScript source code, you would have to define it as a String value: `var jsonString = '{ "foo": 123, "bar": true }'`.

Comment: And thank you both for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var createTree = function (node, data) {
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key == "attributes") {
                node.setAttributes(myAttributes); // loop through attributes on the element
            }
            else {
                for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; ++i) {
                    var childNode = document.createElement(key);
                    createTree(childNode, data[key][i]);
                    node.appendChild(childNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

createTree(parentNode, htmlString);
```

Comment: Thank you, Qnan, I'll test it when I get the chance, but just looking at this, I can see you have included a "data" variable that never gets referenced, and when this is called for the first time, parentNode and "div" will be referencing the same node, won't they? Still, it shows me how to implement the recursive function, so thanks for that.

Comment: @user1565354 sorry, fixed that. "data" actually refers to the subtree of what you refer to as "htmlString" that the function has to process. In the first call, it will be the htmlString itself. "div" was meant to be the top key in the htmlString, and "parentNode" is whatever node you'd like to attach it all to.

Comment: @user1565354 actually it should look somewhat different -- see the edit

Comment: Damn, for some reason IE8 is showing data[key].length as null or not an object, although this solution works in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Ah, there must have been caching. All browsers are showing data[key].length as undefined, which crashes the script.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Qnan's code needed a little tweak, as it wasn't dealing with getting to the end of a end of a branch properly. Once it got to the end, there was nothing to check, and the null length of nothing was causing an error.

I know it is bad practice, but it's late, and I need this fixed, so here is my tweak.

```
var createTree = function (node, data) {
    for (key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key == "attributes") {
                node.setAttributes(myAttributes); // loop through attributes on the element
            }
            else {
                try {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; ++i) {
                        var childNode = document.createElement(key);
                        createTree(childNode, data[key][i]);
                        node.appendChild(childNode);
                    }
                }
                catch(error) {
                    console.log("there was an error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

createTree(parentNode, htmlString);
```

Yes, that's right, I bury the error by try/catching it...and then doing nothing. Don't try this at home kids!

Qnan, many thanks again.

Comment: That's interesting. What input are you feeding it, exactly? The fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/S6ZGK/4/ walks the tree just like in your example, but shows pop-ups instead of setting elements attributes and doesn't seem to cause any errors.

Comment: It would be more like:var htmlString = {
    "div": [{
        "attributes": {
            "class": "myDivClass"
        },
        "p": [{
            "attributes": {
                "class": "myPClass"
            },
            "span": [{
                "attributes": {
                    "class": "mySpan"
                }
            }]
        }],
        "div": [{
            "attributes": {
                "class": "myDiv"
            },
            "span": [{
                "attributes": {
                    "class": "class2"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
};

Comment: And just to make clear, I'm sure any errors arising from the implementation of the code is due to me, not you. :)

Comment: oh, i see... it is an error of mine, actually. Should be `for (var key in data)`, not `for (key in data)`, else `key` is considered global and will be rewritten in every recursive call.

Comment: Everything is serene now, no try/catches required. That is a graceful piece of code, Qnan, thank you. :)