# How to properly iterate through nested arrays with javascript.

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I am having a hard time learning how to iterate through nested arrays, and storing specific array values in javascript.

```
$('#btn2').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var res = hjs.getValue([1,2,3],['bri', 'alert','name', 'hue', 'sat']);
    console.log(res);
});
```

When #btn2 is clicked on, the following is outputed to my console:

[image]

If I'd like to access anyone of these values how would I do so? How do I store the value in a variable?

Comment: console.log(res[0].alert)//for fetching first zero'th element alerts value ;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating through nested objects/arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764142/iterating-through-nested-objects-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can iterate through the object and get the value you want:

```
$('#btn2').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var res = hjs.getValue([1,2,3],['bri', 'alert','name', 'hue', 'sat']);

    for(var i in res)
    {
        if (res.hasOwnProperty(i)) {    
          var obj = res[i];

          console.log('name: ', obj.name);
          console.log('sat: ', obj.sat);
        }
    }
});
```